# Дубликаты в таблице с множественными условиями

Tags: sql, oracle

### Вводные данные

Таблица со зданиями и координатами (в оригинальной таблице более 100 тыс. строк):

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
  building_id int,
  region varchar(55),
  street varchar(55),
  housenumber varchar(55),
  pos_x float,
  pos_y float,
  version int
);

INSERT ALL
    INTO table1(building_id,region, street, housenumber, pos_x, pos_y, version) VALUES(1, 'Moscow','Lenina', '1a', 45.45, 55.55, NULL )
    INTO table1(building_id,region, street, housenumber, pos_x, pos_y, version) VALUES(2, 'Spb','Mira', '20', 45.10, 55.10, NULL )
    INTO table1(building_id,region, street, housenumber, pos_x, pos_y, version) VALUES(3, 'Moscow','Lenina', '1a', 45.85, 55.85, NULL )
    INTO table1(building_id,region, street, housenumber, pos_x, pos_y, version) VALUES(4, 'Moscow', 'Lenina', '1a', 45.85, 55.85, 20 )
    
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

Ссылка на Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/947275/2

### Вывод

| Building_ID | region | street | housenumber | pos_x | pos_y | version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Moscow | Lenina | 1a | 45.45 | 55.55 | NULL |
| 2 | Spb | Mira | 20 | 45.1 | 55.1 | NULL |
| 3 | Moscow | Lenina | 1a | 45.85 | 55.85 | NULL |
| 4 | Moscow | Lenina | 1a | 45.85 | 55.85 | 20 |

### Ожидаемый результат

| Building_ID | region | street | housenumber | pos_x | pos_y | Version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Moscow | Lenina | 1a | 45.45 | 55.55 | NULL |
| 3 | Moscow | Lenina | 1a | 45.85 | 55.85 | NULL |

Необходимо, чтобы в запрос попали одинаковые по ID, region, street, housenumber, но разные по pos_x и pos_y строки. В добавок еще, чтобы и версия была обязательно NULL (поэтому 4 строчка не попадает)

Пробую запрос:

```
SELECT *
FROM MAP_IMPORT A
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM MAP_IMPORT t 
  WHERE a.region = t.region
    AND a.street = t.street
    AND a.housenumber = t.housenumber
    AND a.pos_x <> t.pos_x
    AND a.pos_y <> t.pos_y
    and a.version_delete is null
    and t.version_delete is null
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1  
)
```

sqldeveloper зависает на выполнении. Оставлял на ночь. До сих пор не может справится.
Причем если прошу завершить работу, он даже не ругается (как обычно) на то, чо выполняется запрос. Т.е. просто идёт running, но по факту запрос не выполняется...

[image: Скрин_1]

[image: Скрин]

Comment: А для строчек 1 и 3 должны быть дубликаты?

Comment: Наверное, немного не так объяснил. Нужны дубликаты только по отдельным полям, но чтобы остальные поля (координаты) были разными. Полудубликаты такие.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На входящих данных получилось добиться нужного вам результата следующим запросом

```
SELECT * FROM table3 z
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM table3 x
  WHERE x.region = z.region
  AND x.street = z.street
  AND x.housenumber = z.housenumber
  AND x.pos_x <> z.pos_x
  AND x.pos_y <> z.pos_y
  AND x.building_id <> z.building_id
  AND x.version IS NULL
) 
AND z.version IS NULL;
```

Comment: Запрос работает! Спасибо!!!

Comment: Прошу прощения. А как отредактировать запрос, чтобы учитывался NULL, ну т.е. если в двух строчках совпал адрес, дом, координаты, но в одном из них region NULL, а во втором Moscow, чтобы они тоже попали в выгрузку?

Comment: @lavand0 А как вы планируете обрабатывать null? В целом, можно попробовать изменить строчку `x.region = z.region` на вот такую `(x.region = z.region OR x.region is null)`

Comment: Я подумал, что можно с помощью NVL обработать, он вроде оставляет дефлотное значение, если в поле не Null

Comment: Да, можно. Но что выводить в nvl для разных значений? Допустим проверяется не Moscow а Piter. Как составить nvl? NVL работает так, если в поле(первый параметр null выведет значение, указанное как второй параметр